# XStream collection of type ad subtype

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have classes like this:

```
class A{
//pojo
}
class B extends {
// pojo
}
class C{
@XStreamImplicit( itemFieldName="A")
private ArrayList<A> aList = null;
}
```

The filed aList of class C contains one object type of A.class and one type of B.class.

I can serialize and deserialize  the class to this xml:

```
<c>
 <aList>
  <a/>
  <a/>
 </aList>
</c>
```

But i want xml file to look like this:

```
<c>
 <aList>
  <a/>
  <b/>
 </aList>
</c>
```

Is it possible? And how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@XStreamAlias("a")
public class A {

}

@XStreamAlias("b")
public class B extends A {

}

@XStreamAlias("c")
public class C {
    private ArrayList<A> aList = null;

    public C() {
        aList = new ArrayList<A>();
        aList.add(new A());
        aList.add(new B());
        aList.add(new A());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();

        XStream x = new XStream();
        x.processAnnotations(A.class);
        x.processAnnotations(B.class);
        x.processAnnotations(C.class);

        System.out.println(x.toXML(c));
    }

}
```

and produce:

```
<c>
  <aList>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <a/>
  </aList>
</c>
```

If you dont want to call processAnnotations for every possible class you can write some dynamic code using reflection API and process all classes in loop.